# Are there any torah based books discussing the outdoors, nature, sepcific plants flora or fauna?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, agriculture, biology

Shalom,
I'm trying to find books geared towards nature lovers.
Wanting to go into the forest and identify plants, trees, rock formations and geological phenomena and their characteristics from a Jewish perspective? Perhaps even a book geared to a specific location?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Torah-Encyclopedia-Animal-Kingdom/dp/159264404X

Comment: There are books on the flora and fauna of Israel; in fact, Rabbi Dr. Slifkin (see above) did his dissertation about such books. But if you want to walk around in North America and and identify plants, find a North American botany book. How a scientist identifies a plant or rock is going to be how anyone would do it, there's not really a "Jewish perspective." (Though Jewish law may then try to determine how said plant/rock fits in Jewish law; someone just wrote a whole book about whether a pineapple is a "fruit" or "vegetable" vis-a-vis Jewish law.)

Answer (score 1):

Professor Yehuda Feliks wrote well-regarded books identifying the flora and fauna of the Bible and Talmud. Unfortunately they are hard to find.

Also look at Perek Shirah, which assigns a verse to many different animal species. It has been printed in many editions, and you can find commentaries explaining the connection of a verse to an animal.